# What is wrong with RuleCondition here?

Tags: bugs, evaluation

**Bug introduced in 9.0 or earlier and fixed in 10.4**

---

```
Hold@1`5 /. x_Real :> RuleCondition[N@x, True]
Hold@1`5 /. x_Real :> RuleCondition[N@2`5, True]
Hold@2`5 /. x_Real :> RuleCondition[N@2`5, True]
Hold@1`5 /. x_Real :> RuleCondition[N@t, True]
```

The returned answers, in `StandardForm`, are:

```
Hold[1.0000]
Hold[2.]
Hold[2.0000]
Hold[t]
```

The problem is that the first and third lines should evaluate to machine precision numbers (like the 2nd line), but it appears that *Mathematica* is executing an approximate numerical equality test to determine whether or not to execute the `RuleCondition` that doesn't show up during my attempts at tracing. Experts, do you consider this to be a bug? What would your workaround be? The context is that I am tracing a numerical routine that works with high precision numbers. I need to format the trace so that I can actually read it, thus the conversion to machine precision numbers that are inside a Hold (`HoldForm` in the case of `Trace`).

For those that don't know, `RuleCondition` is what the right hand side of a `Rule` or `RuleDelayed` evaluates to if that right hand side contains an expression like `Block[{},result/;condition]`, which is transformed to `RuleCondition[result,condition]` and is evaluated outside of the context of the expression that originally matched the left hand side pattern of the `Rule` or `RuleDelayed`. `RuleCondition` right hand side replacements don't happen if condition is `False`. However, in this case, it appears that the condition must be `True` AND the result must not be approximately equal to the left hand side pattern for the rule.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: I am pretty sure you are the very first *new user* that asked a question about something as advanced as `RuleCondition`. Additionally, your post is as clearly written and formatted as one can only wish for! Let me welcome you here and hope, you stay longer.

Comment: Just like you said. This bug is fixed in v10.4.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Update Jan 22nd: WRI Tech Support indicates that the fixes for all the test cases below, including the ones that don't depend on `SameQ`, ***may*** land in the next point release. The fixes could miss the point release if they cause other problems with higher severity.

It appears that there may be some indirect dependence on `RuleCondition` as well as other structures. I found this out while trying to explain the problem to WRI technical support.

In all cases, these answers should be a number (1. or 2.) followed by answers with that same number in a list. The spots where the number has extra zeroes indicate a rule that went unused when it should have been. Note the difference between the second to last cases for 1. vs. 2., which appear to depend on the use of `RuleCondition` and the size of the number (which affects the `SameQ` code).

```
In[1]:= $Version
Out[1]= "10.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 29, 2014)"

In[2]:= 1`5 /. {1`5 :> 1.}
Out[2]= 1.

In[3]:= {1`5} /. {1`5 :> 1.}
Out[3]= {1.0000}

In[4]:= {1`5} /. {1`5 :> 1. + 0}
Out[4]= {1.}

In[5]:= {1`5} /. {1`5 :> 1. + $MachineEpsilon}
Out[5]= {1.}

In[6]:= Block[{Internal`$SameQTolerance = -Infinity}, {1`5} /. {1`5 :>1. + $MachineEpsilon}]
Out[6]= {1.}

In[7]:= Block[{Internal`$SameQTolerance = -Infinity}, {1.`5} /. x_Real :> RuleCondition[N[x] + $MachineEpsilon, True]]
Out[7]= {1.}

In[8]:= Block[{Internal`$SameQTolerance = -Infinity}, {1.`5} /. x_Real :> N[x] + $MachineEpsilon]
Out[8]= {1.}

In[9]:= 2`5 /. {2`5 :> 2.}
Out[9]= 2.

In[10]:= {2`5} /. {2`5 :> 2.}
Out[10]= {2.0000}

In[11]:= {2`5} /. {2`5 :> 2. + 0}
Out[11]= {2.}

In[12]:= {2`5} /. {2`5 :> 2. + $MachineEpsilon}
Out[12]= {2.}

In[13]:= Block[{Internal`$SameQTolerance = -Infinity}, {2`5} /. {2`5 :>2. + $MachineEpsilon}]
Out[13]= {2.}

In[14]:= Block[{Internal`$SameQTolerance = -Infinity}, {2.`5} /. x_Real :> RuleCondition[N[x] + $MachineEpsilon, True]]
Out[14]= {2.0000}

In[15]:= Block[{Internal`$SameQTolerance = -Infinity}, {2.`5} /. x_Real :> N[x] + $MachineEpsilon]
Out[15]= {2.}
```

Comment: BTW, the complete, and completely-ridiculous-it's-required, workaround is, as Oleksandr hinted, related to the size of an Ulp. ``Block[{Internal`$SameQTolerance = -Infinity}, 
 Hold@7.26776695296636881100211090526212259821208984422118509147084967
2488415598077633798562984417909551965918767307788640371281156045069813
4215158051518709271734`133.50224952160673 /. 
  x_Real :> RuleCondition[N@x + Ulp@x, True]]`` actually fires and rounds correctly.

Comment: Yes, `2. + $MachineEpsilon` is still `2.`, but `1. + $MachineEpsilon` is slightly bigger than 1. I added `$MachineEpsilon` in my answer because the value was 1, but in general one should of course multiply by `(1. + $MachineEpsilon)` to get a result that is one ulp bigger.

Comment: ``Log[10^Internal`$SameQTolerance]/Log[2] == 1.``, i.e. `SameQ` applies by default a 1-bit tolerance (requires a 2-ulp difference for comparands to differ). I always thought this tolerance should be zero for `SameQ`, which of course is possible only with ``Internal`$SameQTolerance = -Infinity``.

Comment: @OleksandrR. did you see the last two examples for 2. (Out@14 and Out@15)? They show a difference in the presence and absence of `RuleCondition`. Also, Out@11 vs. Out@10 shows other types of structural differences that cause the rule to trigger. There seem to be times when `SameQ` by itself isn't the deciding factor for numeric replacements.

Comment: Yes, and I can't explain why that is. Perhaps `RuleCondition` uses some numerical tests additional to `SameQ`. I think the only people who can answer this properly are at WRI, so it's good that you have raised this with them. Please post an answer with their comments/response when you get it.

Answer (score 13):

Here is an observation, not really an answer:

```
Hold@1.`5 /. x_Real :> RuleCondition[N[x] + $MachineEpsilon, True]
(* -> Hold[1.0000] *)
```

But:

```
Block[{Internal`$SameQTolerance = -Infinity},
```

Hold@1.`5 /. x_Real :> RuleCondition[N[x] + $MachineEpsilon, True]
    ]
    (* -> Hold[1.] *)

It does not help your test case because `` 1.`5 `` is `SameQ` `1.` But I think this makes it a question of `SameQ`'s problem, rather than `RuleCondition`'s.

For completeness: `` Internal`$EqualTolerance `` and `` Internal`$HashTolerance `` have no effect. The test is definitely `SameQ`.

Since [Alexey](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/280/alexey-popkov) mentions that [things were better in version 5 with respect to a tangentially related bug/oddity](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/94413/what-is-wrong-with-rulecondition-here/94414#comment255387_94414), it may be worth noting as well that in versions of *Mathematica* up to and including 7, we have a different result:

```
Hold@1`5 /. x_Real :> RuleCondition[N@x, True]
(* -> Hold[1.] *)
Hold@1`5 /. x_Real :> RuleCondition[N@2`5, True]
(* -> Hold[2.] *)
Hold@2`5 /. x_Real :> RuleCondition[N@2`5, True]
(* -> Hold[2.] *)
Hold@1`5 /. x_Real :> RuleCondition[N@t, True]
(* -> Hold[t] *)
```

This looks absolutely as one would expect. The optimization of `SameQ` in version 8 is the clear culprit.

Unfortunately, we cannot work around the problem by replacing `SameQ` with a more stringent test:

```
Internal`HashSameQ[1., 1.`5]
(* -> False *)

Block[{SameQ = Internal`HashSameQ, Internal`$HashTolerance = -Infinity}, 
 Hold@1.`5 /. x_Real :> RuleCondition[N[x], True]
]
(* -> Hold[1.0000] *)
```

It seems that `RuleCondition` is hard-coded to call the `SameQ` code no matter how `SameQ` is defined at the top level. This might be considered a bug in `RuleCondition` in addition to the one in `SameQ`.

I am of the view that the `SameQ` behavior is a bug, because while I have always thought that the value of `` Internal`$SameQTolerance `` being anything other than `-Infinity` is a bad idea, for numbers with different `Precision` to compare as being the same is an explicit violation of *Mathematica*'s numerical model of floating-point numbers being distributions. I think one cannot have a serious conceptual inconsistency like this and not call it a bug.

Comment: +1 Beat me to it by seconds.  `RuleCondition` is unnecessary to demonstrate the behaviour.  It appears that the `SameQ` "optimization" only occurs if a structure needs to be rebuilt.  For example, contrast the results of evaluating ``2`5 /. 2`5 -> 2.`` and ``{2`5} /. 2`5 -> 2.``.  The need to rebuild the list in the second case is enough to trigger the "optimization".

Comment: @WReach You need to double quote your code. Start and end with two backticks, then you can use one backtick in the middle and it is displayed correctly.

Comment: @OleksandrR. Can you tell me what happens in your Mathematica if you copy the code ``2`5 /. 2`5 -> 2.`` and paste it into a notebook? [Here is](http://i.stack.imgur.com/PJAzc.png) what I get :-)

Comment: @halirutan I got the same. Two bugs for the price of one?

Comment: @halirutan It is related to a well-known bug with missing whitespace between `\.` and `2` which persists from the very first version of the system and described by Richard Fateman in his [critical article on *Mathematica*](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~fateman/papers/mma.review.pdf) (see chapter 7.5).

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov I found a similar bug myself some time ago. When I copy and paste this `25.6*^1.5` into a notebook, I end up [with this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/d8EDj.png) which translates to `Times[5,Repeated[256]]` and is complete non-sense. You need to know that it *should* be parsed as `25.6*^1 * 0.5` because only integers are allowed as exponent with `*^`. It is done correctly when you type it in. I could not convince the support@WRI that this is a bug and eventually, I gave up.

Comment: @halirutan I just checked both cases in *Mathematica* 5.2 and both are pasted correctly! Moreover, the evaluation behavior is different, see [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/q5myF1h.png). So I was wrong: these bugs were not present in version 5 and are not related to the well known whitespace bug I described above.

Comment: @WReach It seems the "optimization" was introduced after version 5 where your examples demonstrate consistent behavior, see screenshot in my comment above.